JSON_EQUAL in PL/SQL
How can I compare two JSON_OBJECT_T?
I have a PL/SQL procedure. I am getting a return of an array of JSON OBJECT from the GET request from HTTP API endpoint. I have prepared a JSON_OBJECT_T record REC1.
I am trying to compare REC1 with every record in the return array from the GET request. So as to figure out if I need to do an UPDATE request or PUT request for REC1.
I am in Oracle 19C, and I am trying to use JSON_EQUAL to compare the JSON_OBJECT_T, but I am getting the following error:

PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_EQUAL' must be declared

How can I achieve this in PL/SQL? Is there another efficient method to achieve this?
Tried JSON_EQUAL.

Expecting: Return Boolean if equal


JSON_EQUALS is not supported in PL/SQL expressions. But you should be able to use it in SQL within PL/SQL. A [mcve] might be helpful.

JSON_EQUALS is not supported in PL/SQL expressions, and will throw that exception.
You can use it in SQL within PL/SQL, but it seems you have to do a few extra steps when you're starting from JSON_ARRAY_T and JSON_OBJECT_T.
If you have an array and an object declared something like:
declare
  l_array json_array_t;
  l_object json_object_t;

and populated from your HTTP call or manually, then you need string versions declared, with your object converted to a string once, and each array element also converted to a string as you loop over the array.
  l_clob_1 := l_object.to_clob;
  <<json_loop>>
  for i in 0..l_array.get_size - 1 loop
    l_clob_2 := l_array.get(i).to_clob;

You can then use a SQL query to call JSON_EQUAL using those strings:
    select case when json_equal(l_clob_1, l_clob_2) then 1 else 0 end
    into l_match_num
    from dual;

You can then set your boolean flag, and break the loop, if that returns 1.
    if l_match_num = 1 then
      l_match_boo := true;
      exit json_loop;
    end if;
  end loop;

You can then use that boolean value however you need to.
So putting that together as a demo with made-up data:
declare
  l_array json_array_t;
  l_object json_object_t;
  l_clob_1 clob;
  l_clob_2 clob;
  l_match_num number;
  l_match_boo boolean;
begin
  l_array := json_array_t('[{"id": 1, "value":"hello"},{"id": 2, "value":"world"}]');
  l_object := json_object_t('{"id": 2, "value":"world"}');

  l_clob_1 := l_object.to_clob;
  <<json_loop>>
  for i in 0..l_array.get_size - 1 loop
    l_clob_2 := l_array.get(i).to_clob;
    select case when json_equal(l_clob_1, l_clob_2) then 1 else 0 end
    into l_match_num
    from dual;

    if l_match_num = 1 then
      dbms_output.put_line('Index ' || i || ' matched');
      l_match_boo := true;
      exit json_loop;
    end if;
  end loop;

  if l_match_boo then
    dbms_output.put_line('Match');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('No match');
  end if;
end;
/

which output:
Index 1 matched
Match

fiddle
The context switching will affect the efficiency but how much maybe depends on the amount of data. You could potentially convert the array to a temporary table of JSON strings and then query that in once go, rather than one element at a time, but that might end up being more work and less efficient.


I am getting a return of an array of JSON OBJECT from GET request from HTTP API endpoint

If you are actually getting a string and parsing that into a JSON_ARRAY_T then you can probably approach this completely differently by using other functions like JSON_TABLE to parse it instead, and then doing the entire parse/comparison in a single SQL query. You haven't shown what you're actually ding though, so that may not be possible.
